# Best practice for separating configure and algorithm code

Tags: c++

I'm writing some code to do scientific computing in c++, and I need to do some calculation on a custom structure `foo`. To make the whole thing more easy to maintain in the future, I want to separate the code that sets up structure such as `foo.bar=1;` etc in a separate file. How to achieve that? The structure uses the armadillo library to support matrix/linear algebra. I already wrote the header file `f.hpp` like:

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <complex>
using namespace arma;

#ifndef __fn__
#define __fn__

struct foo
{
    cx_mat a;
    mat b;
    cx_cube c;
    complex<double> d;
    string desc;
};

#endif
```

Comment: @AlexFarber And how to include that in my main program to make it aware of this new file?

Comment: This can be done by using the `include` directive; I suggest creating a function e.g. called `init`, defining it in a separate file and calling the function from the main program.

Comment: @Codor thanks. Suppose the file in which the function `init` resides is called `init.cpp`, and I wrote `#include "init.cpp"` in my main program and invoke `g++ main.cpp` just as if there's no separate file?

Comment: This might work, but I believe that usually two files `init.cpp` and `init.h` would be used.

Comment: @Codor I tried `#include "init.cpp"` and `#include init.h` in my main file but the compiler complains about `foo` already defined. However, my header file has a `#ifndef` guard. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's possible; it is hard to tell from the distance.

Comment: You're header guards are reserved identifiers. Don't use double underscores!

Comment: What is your program doing? What is your audience (scientists, engineers, .... in what domain?)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It's a simulation program for my own research project and I'm mostly likely to be the only one to use/maintain it. I just want to save some headaches years later when i have to use this code to deal with some other systems and have to read the whole thing again.

Comment: @davidsedai: I believe that learning how to use interpreters is worthwhile. Choose a technology which is familiar to your domain (or else `guile`, see [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding it to a source-code file will require you to compile it every-time you wish to change the values. And this is a bad practice, especially if your compilation time is 'long'.

The recommended way is to have config file say 'foo.ini'. You could have a flexible config file, if you use a third-party/open-source library such as https://code.google.com/p/inih/ or http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/.

But, if you want to keep is simple, try this convention:
Config file with alternate line of key-value pairs, with a fixed expected order. For example:

```
# foo.bar
42
# foo.pub
You're awesome
# foo.club
24/06/2015
# tab.a
64
```

Note that the order of the values are important and that will make it easy for us to parse using simple C++ code. Just open the file and call getLine() repeatedly, ignore every other line and parse the second line to store it into the structure.

If you want to store a complicated structure such-as a matrix, you can device a simple strategy to store such structures, as the parsing function is also written by us:

```
# Foo matrix rows
100
# Foo matrix cols
50
# Foo matrix elements, row-by-row:
0.5 3 5 23 ... ... 100
4 5 5 34 1 ... ... 100
.
.
3 33 33 2 ...  ... 100

# Diagonal Matrix rows-cols
20
# Diagonal Values, row-by-row others 0
45
22
92
.
.
20
```

Also note that libconfig (http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/) allows you to store and represent such complex data-structures, using array and Json like text. You can use that if you would like a full-fledged 'config-language' to start with.

And you save a lot of compilation time. Just update the config file and re-run the program. That way, other programs could feed-in the config-values.

Comment: The code is indeed quite complex and compilation takes a while. However, the initialization requires complex matrix initialization which is tough to achieve in an initialization file: suppose I need a diagonal matrix whose diagonal element is sqrt(1), sqrt(2)...sqrt(100) then doing this in a plain text initialization file is not a good option.

Comment: @davidsedai Have updated the answer to consider the case of complex data. You could choose libconfig or write your own simple parser.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility, quite common in scentific HPC, it to embed some scripting language in your application.

You could embed a [Lua](http://lua.org) or [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile) (or Ocaml) interpreter in your application, and have it interpret some initialization script before running your complex computation. That user provided script could do some simple interpreted computation to initialize your data. You just need to provide some scripting primitives to manipulate (& create) your data that the user would combine with his scripts.

You could also make your application an extension (or plugin) of some existing framework like [Scilab](http://scilab.org/), [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave), [R](http://www.r-project.org), [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html), [NekoVM](http://nekovm.org/)

BTW, your program could also read some simple data (perhaps using textual [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) formats like [Json](http://json.org/)) and your users would themselves write some other script or program to feed yours (e.g. using [Unix pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29)).

Another way might be to initialize your thing in C++, which might be generated (perhaps even by your program from some higher-level input), and compile that C++ code at runtime and then [dynamically load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) it as a plugin using [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) (I am doing such things in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)...).

Be aware that embedding or integrating some interpreter is a major software architectural design choice, and you should make that choice early.